# Why am I getting 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'pk' when I login?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am building a backend authentication in `Django-Rest_framework` using `django-rest-auth` and REST framework JWT Auth and when I login I keep getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
AttributeError at /api/auth/login/
'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'pk'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'pk'
Exception Location: D:\Python Workspace\Rest_Gama\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_jwt\utils.py, line 86, in jwt_create_payload
Python Executable:  D:\Python Workspace\Rest_Gama\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7
```

This is my `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    profile = models.ImageField(default='user_default_m.png', upload_to='profile/', blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
```

This is my `serializers.py`

```
from rest_auth.serializers import LoginSerializer as RestAuthLoginSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers

from users.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('pk', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile', 'dob', 'date_joined', 'last_login')
        read_only_fields = ('pk', 'email', 'date_joined', 'last_login')


class LoginSerializer(RestAuthLoginSerializer):
    username = None
```

Comment: pk refers to 'primary_key' but it  is not a field name. Change 'pk' to 'id' and see it that works for you.

Comment: @YousufM.N I changed, but result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling `REST framework JWT Auth`

```
pip install djangorestframework-jwt
```

Documentations for reference -> [here](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)

Comment: You know what? as surprising as it may sound it worked! Thanks